# What’s the most common way to debug C++ on Mac

Tags: gdb, debug

I'm wondering what's the most common way to debug C++ programs using emacs for Mac users? I’m currently using gdb, which takes a moment for me to make it work for Mac, so I’m now considering give dap-mode a try.

I’m new to emacs. Just wanna know what most Mac users do to debug C++ on Mac?

Comment: Have you looked into options for installing `gdb` on your Mac, e.g., using Macports with the executable named `ggdb`?

Comment: The question encourages opinion-based answers, so it should be closed. If you want to ask for a way to debug C++ code on a Mac, then do that. Questions asking for "the best way" to do something are better posed in an opinion/discussion site such as Reddit.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your suggestions. I have modified my question.

Comment: I’ve managed to use gdb, with some efforts though.. Not a good experience making gdb work on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't debug C++ from within Emacs, but have you looked into `clang/lldb`? You can use either Apple's native version or a version from upstream. I get mine via Homebrew (`brew install llvm`). `dap-mode` [supports](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/#lldb) `lldb`. It's also supported by [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud) (along with a [host of others](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/wiki/Debuggers-Available)), and its `realgud--lldb` extension.